# How to create a comment in a Pull Request without using thread

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I have a script that posts a thread into a pull request:

```
$createThreadInPRUrl = "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$project/_apis/git/repositories/$repositoryId/pullRequests/$pullRequestId/threads?api-version=5.0"
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $createThreadInPRUrl -Headers @{Authorization = $pat } -Body $body -Method Post -ContentType 'application/json'

$body = @"
    {
        "comments": [
            {
                "content": "
                    \nLink to feature release $env:featureReleaseUrl\nOne or more Cypress tests failed.\nLink to Cypress test results $cypressResultatenUrl",
                "CommentThreadStatus": "closed"
            }
        ]
    }
"@
```

And this works fine:

[image]

But I don't want to use threads. I want to create something like a commit update:

[image]

What API call can I use to do that?

Comment: There is really a new commit?

Comment: No. This script is run in the release. The release can be released from triggering a build manually or from committing into the PR or creating a PR. I want to post a message but not something that has to be resolved or replied to. So more in line of the message the commit does.

Comment: Oh ok, now I understand. there is a `commentType` property but it look like it doesn't work :/